# How to optimise Drools execution Performance?

Tags: drools

We have 1000 rules under a single Rule flow Group
We have severe performance issue while executing (around 10-20 secs)

We thought instead of having under single Rule Flow group,Splitting into multiple Agenda group will improve the performance.

Or creating multiple entry points increase the performance?

Anyone came across this problem?

Any Links /documentation also welcomed.

Comment: Multiple agenda groups won't help as the workload remains the same, only the order of firing is influenced. An entry point is nothing like an additional attribute, added on the fly; if all facts of a type come from the same entry point it won't improve things either. - Most of the time, performance issues result from inadequate use of patterns and constraints. You'll have to provide insight into your rules, otherwise you won't get any help.

Comment: Thanks @laune ..We are actually using rules for calculating premium in Insurance domain.We Basically select multiple factors based on the risk and using the selected factors we'll calculate the premium.
One of our Factor Selection Rule contains 87000 rules which is implemented in Decision table under single RuleFlow Group.

We already did this kind of premium calculation in Drools but we have significantly less number rules ..

FYI 
We are doing update(fact) almost every rule..

Answer (score 2):

There was a similar issue several months ago on the Drools user list, and it was resolved successfully by a different approach according to may proposal. It may be applicable here, too.

Let's say there are some risk factors that influence the premium for a car insurance. Attributes are: age, previous incidents, amount of damage in previous incidents, gender, medical classification.

Each of these values influences the premium by a few credits.

You can write tons of rules like

```
Application( age <= 32 && <=35, previous == 1, damage <= 1000,
             gender == 'F', medical == 0.25 )
then
setPremium( 421 );
```

The proposed solution was to insert (constant) facts for each such parameter set and have a single rule that determines the matching parameter set and setting the premium from the field in the parameter set.